# Callback function - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have generic function i need to use in different places. The issue is some places i need to pass function without parameters and some places with parameters to call back function. How can i handle in both the scenarios.

```
    function deletePrompt(message, callback){
    $("#deleteModelWindow").modal({
    containerCss: {
        width: 320,
        height: 180,
        overflow: 'hidden'},
        onShow: function(dialog){ dialog.wrap.css('overflow','hidden'); }
    });
    document.getElementById("spanid").innerHTML = message;       
    $("#deleteModelWindow").on('click', "#deleteConfirm", function(){
    if (callback !== undefined) {
        callback();           
    } else {    
        callback(parameter1,parameter2);        
    }
    $.modal.close();
    });     
    $("#deleteModelWindow").on('click', "#cancel", function(){          
    $.modal.close();
    });
```

}

calling From:

```
<input id="deleteInvitationBtn" class="buOrange large" type="button" name="submit" value="Delete Invitation" onClick="deletePrompt('Are you sure you want to delete the invitation?', deleteInvitation('${invitation.invitationId}','${invitation.clientActivationCode}'))">
```

Here, In onclick before it redirects to deletePrompt() it is directly redirecting to the deleteInvitation().

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You can handle it in the callback function by using the "arguments" object right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object or check if `message` and `callback` are undefined:

```
function deletePrompt(message, callback) {
        $("#deleteModelWindow").modal({
        containerCss: {
            width: 320,
            height: 180,
            overflow: 'hidden'},
            onShow: function(dialog){ dialog.wrap.css('overflow','hidden'); }
        });

        if (message !== undefined) {
             document.getElementById("spanid").innerHTML = message;
        }

        if (callback !== undefined) {
            $("#deleteModelWindow").on('click', "#deleteConfirm", function() {           
              callback();
              callback(parameter1,parameter2);

              $.modal.close();
            }); 
        }

        $("#deleteModelWindow").on('click', "#cancel", function(){          
        $.modal.close();
        });   
}
```

JSFiddle demonstrating the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/on3b7sv4/

It may also be better to split the binding logic up into smaller functions so the function is cleaner.

Comment: you can see below how i am calling the function.                                onclick="deletePrompt('Are you sure you want to delete the user?', deleteUser)">                                                    onClick="deletePrompt('Are you sure you want to delete the invitation?',deleteInvitation, deleteInvitation('${invitation.invitationId}','${invitation.clientActivationCode}'))"

Comment: sorry not working.  I am using as below.    For me callback is returning false     $("#deleteModelWindow").on('click', "#deleteConfirm", function(){
        if (callback !== undefined) {
            callback(parameter1,parameter2);           
        } else { 
   callback();  
  }
        $.modal.close();
        });

Comment: onclick only it's calling deleteInvitation method.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. JavaScript functions are really flexible, you can pass them more arguments than they expect, or fewer; within the function, any declared argument that you don't pass will have the value `undefined`. Any *undeclared* argument you pass will be available as part of the `arguments` pseudo-array.

Example:

```js
function test(label, a, b) {
  var n;
  snippet.log("------- " + label);
  snippet.log("a = " + a);
  snippet.log("c = " + b);
  if (arguments.length > 3) {
    snippet.log("Extra arguments:");
    for (n = 3; n < arguments.length; ++n) {
      snippet.log("#" + n + ": " + arguments[n]);
    }
  }
}
test("test1", 1, 2);
test("test2", 1);
test("test3");
test("test4", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```